# Two different errors when joining this site

Tags: bug, login

I'm an old user on this website. I wanted to join the Code Review community just now, so I clicked the "join this community" button on the top navbar, got a page with a fancy blue button so I click to confirm joining the community.

The first time I clicked the button, I got a "500" page containing some bold phrase saying "this is our fault." I repeated the process and I got a 404 instead.

I clicked over the home button and I saw myself joined in the community.

I have no idea what caused each of these errors. I would be happy to help debugging the issue if there's anything I can do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the HTTP-500 error was logged and SE devs are already looking into it. Only SE devs have access to server-side source code though, but anyway, your account seems to be correctly created now - welcome aboard! Feel free to hop into [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), meet the site's regulars and ask any question you might have about this site. [This meta post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) is probably a good place to start. See you around!